# computing which function is above another function

Tags: calculus

Say we are trying to find the area between two functions.

So for example we have $y=e^x$ and $y=x^2-1$,$x=-1, x=1$. Graphing (or just knowing how these functions look) clearly shows $e^x$ is greater then $y=x^2-1$ within $[-1,1]$ but how would you figure that out in a mathematical way without graphing and seeing it visually?

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives?

Comment: Yes. Covered those a long time ago.

Comment: What about $e^x > 0 \ge x^2 -1$ on that interval?

Comment: find derivative of $f(x)=e^x-x^2+1$ and show that it's positive on the interval

Comment: @Vasya:  But of course if the derivative of $f(x)-g(x)$ is *not* everywhere positive in the interval, that does not mean that $f(x)$ is not always greater than $g(x)$.  So your approach really isn't that helpful.

Comment: @David G Stock: Agreed

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: if derivative is positive, we only need to check the value of $f(x)-g(x)$ at $x=-1$

Comment: @Vasya:  Of course... *IF*.  But if *NOT* everywhere positive, then what????

Comment: There is no “universal” method that works for any function.

Comment: If you assume that $h(x) \equiv f(x) - g(x)$ is continuous, then the question reduces to testing for existence of zeros in $h(x)$ in the interval.  There are some theorems on that, but (I think) nothing universally applicable.